# Get directory name, folder name and count of all files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to create a script to read each folder name in a directory, count of zip files in each folder and then count of files in each zip. The output need to be written in an output file.

I came up with below:

```
 $ZipRoot = 'C:\Users\Main Folder'
 $ZipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipRoot -Recurse -Filter '*.zip'
 $Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
 $Results = foreach( $ZipFile in $ZipFiles ){
     $FileCount = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.FullName).Items() |
            Measure-Object |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
    [pscustomobject]@{
      FullName = $ZipFile.FullName
      FileCount = $FileCount
      }
    }
 $Results |
 Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\mlkstq\Desktop\FFNS\ZipReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output

```
            Fullname                                 Filecount
            C:\Users\Main Folder\Subfolder1\Zip1     3
            C:\Users\Main Folder\Subfolder2\Zip2     5
```

The problem is that I am having trouble getting the Subfolder name in putput file. Also want to substring subfolder name to get valid name. Whatever i try it fails.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to archive, could you add an expected output file as an example?

Answer (score 0):

If I've got you right I'd do it this way:

```
$ZipRoot = 'C:\Users\Main Folder'
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

$subFolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path $ZipRoot -Recurse -Directory
$Result = foreach ($subFolder in $subFolderList) {
    $zipFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $subFolder.FullName -File -Filter *.zip
    foreach ($ZipFile in $zipFileList) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            subFolder     = $subFolder.FullName
            zipFilesCount = $zipFileList.Count
            zipFile       = $ZipFile.Name
            fileCount     = $Shell.NameSpace($zipFile.FullName).Items().Count
        }
    }
}
Format-Table -InputObject $Result -AutoSize -InputObject $Result
Export-Csv -InputObject $Result -Path 'C:\Users\mlkstq\Desktop\FFNS\ZipReport.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

In my opinion it just does not look that good to have the count of the zip files per subfolder repeated for each line of the subfolder